# sharepoint lists - identical permission list - different user access

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Sharepoint 2007 SP3 with December CU.
One site, two lists. Permissions are not inherited and looks like these:

List1:
group1 - contribute
group2 - read
portal owners - full control

List2:
group3 - contribute
group4 - read
portal owners - full control

The problem's that List1 can access only users from group1, group2 and portal owners,
but to List2 all users have read access!

If I create a new list on the same site or on a new site then everyone will have read access to it no matter what's in permission list.
But if I set a custom permissions on an item in a list then it works as it should be.

Anonymous login is disabled in Cental administration for this application. Windows log is clear.

What else could it be?

Comment: Most probably all users are within group3 or group4. But this isn't a Stackoverflow question. Try sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: I took this 2 groups as an example. The problem's within the whole sharepoint site
Thanks for a link!